# Why is StringBuilder final - versus having all final methods?

Tags: java

The motivation for this was my answer ("Wishful thinking") to an [earlier question on StringBuilder best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446994/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-private-methods-return-string-instead-of-pas/7447512#7447512).  If StringBuilder was extensible, then domain-specific subclasses could extend its fluent interface, which would tighten up code where a StringBuilder gets passed around to a lot of methods that build parts of a larger string.

I'm considering suggesting something - maybe a StringBuilder delegate -  to the Guava folks.

What additional purpose does it serve for StringBuilder to be final, as opposed to just having final methods?

Comment: I think delegation is the right way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all methods are final then the current behaviour of StringBuilder cannot be modified. Subclasses of it must add either unconnected behaviour (which is inherently bad design) or new functionality which uses the old, such as convenience methods. If you want to do the latter it is probably better to have a class that provides the relevant functionality but contains a StringBuilder rather than extends it. As Joshua Bloch says, "prefer containment over inheritence". In short, if all methods are final there is no good reason to extend the class, and you may as well make it final too.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't want to have to delegate all the methods in StringBuilder in every subclass, and the subclasses definitely need access to a lot of them, in order to do things like `builder.appendMyBeginning().append('.').appendMyEnd()`.  So in practice, are you suggesting a generic delegate with an identical set of methods, that then would be subclassed?

Comment: That could work. I would expect that a particular use of StringBuilder probably wouldn't want ALL StringBuilder's methods. You could implement and delegate the ones you needed, and add any extras you wanted.

Comment: As Joshua Bloch also says, "avoid creating unnecessary objects" ;) In general, I think this whole thing with `AbstractStringBuilder`, `Appendable`, `PrintWriter`, `Writer`, `PrintStream` and `OutputStream` is an example of a bad design.  It's obvious, they all must share some common more reacher interface that must allow appending various primitive types in a uniform way. ...

Comment: ... Instead, `Appendable`, `Writer` and `OutputStream` implementations diverged into countless specializations all doing the same thing. What is the difference between appending a long value to `StringBuilder` and writing it to `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream`? Just a rhetorical question. That's just a nightmare if there is requirement to support string builders, writers and streams simultaneously, it's all about wrappers around wrappers. No offense, just whining :)

Comment: I disagree. For example I'd just like to add an appendLine() method that is identical to append, but if there is already content adds a newline separator. This is not unconnected behavior, and I don't want to alter behavior of any existing methods. It is extremely painful to have to replicate pass-through methods for all the existing methods, in order to create a container.