# Why is stringbuffer final?

Tags: java

The string class is immutable and one of reasons behind that is the class is declared as final though there are other reasons also.
But why is StringBuffer or StringBuilder final and still they are mutable?
So what other factors are deciding for String to be immutable?

Comment: I think you may be confusing the concept of `final` i.e. non-extensibility and immutable.

Comment: Relevant discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448515/why-is-stringbuilder-final-versus-having-all-final-methods

Comment: @jdphenix for a class to be truely immutable it should be final, to avoid extending to add mutation

Comment: @SteveKuo I agree. abhilash seems to believe they believe that a final class is inherently immutable, which is obviously not correct. I may have misread however.

Comment: @jdphenix I know what a final modifier does to a class, but i confused on what basis is String class immutable because everywhere they say its final   .But StringBuffer too is final so what other factor?

Comment: @abhilash I believe this may help understanding https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Comment: So what’s your question now? Do you want to know why `StringBuilder` etc. is `final` or do you want to know what makes `String` immutable?

Comment: An immutable class is a class whose instance state can't change after they have been constructed. A final class is a class that can't be extended. Those are almost orthogonal concepts. The only link between them is that immutable classes are final so that you can't create subclasses that would add mutable state to the base class.

Comment: @JBNizet: I'm not sure that last sentence is really accurate; making constructors package-private and only providing package-private immutable subclasses (a la `ImmutableList`) also suffices.

Comment: @LouisWasserman agreed. I didn't meant that making the class final was the only way to prevent subclasses to add mutable state. What I meant is that, when an immutable chooses to be final, the reason is to prevent subclasses to add mutable state. You're actually proving my point even more: immutability and final-classes are orthogonal concepts: a class can be immutable without being final, and a final class can be mutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` are mainly used for string concatenating operations within a single method, the code using them often being generating by the compiler. So being extended is not the typical use case.

On the other hand, being `final` allows better optimizations within a JVM, at least in the past; today’s HotSpot JVM does not require it, however, there never was a reason to change the `final` declaration from these classes.

Note that extending `StringBuilder` and overriding methods for polymorphic behavior would be a bit pointless as there is no `public` method within the entire JRE accepting or returning `StringBuilder` instance (besides within `StringBuilder` itself). There are [`Appendable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) and [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) filling this gap and offering much more flexibility.

The concepts of *mutability* and *immutability* are entirely different from the concept of `final` classes. They simply depend on what kind of methods or operations a class provides. `String` has no methods that allow modifying its contents while `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` have such methods. Declaring an immutable class `final` just helps prohibiting subclasses which could introduce methods supporting mutation, but that’s not a hard requirement.

Comment: I wanted to add simple functionality like appendln to string builder, which would basically do sb.append(str).append("\n"), instead of putting a static method accepting a stringbuilder, I thought it would be cleaner to extend stringbuilder with the couple appendln implementations. So for this small use-case it would have been usfeul to extend it. Does anyone have a better solution in this case? Cause I am not sure if it would be viable using Appendable or CharSequence instead, and extending would have been much easier.

Comment: @AgentM all of `StringBuilder`’s `append` methods have been declared to return `StringBuilder` rather than your hypothetical subclass. So when using the inherited `append` methods, `yourBuilder.append(x).appendLn(y)` wouldn’t work, as after the first invocation of an (inherited) `append` method, the compiler would complain about `StringBuilder` not having your new method. Unless you override all of those methods to return a more specific type, i.e. your subclass. But when you have to override all methods anyway, extending is not easier than delegating.

Comment: @Holger very good point! For me that is the "correct" answer!

Answer (score 2):

Why String is final and immutable are actually *two*, partially independent, questions.

First, String is part of the java.lang package, as the name suggests the types in this package are related to implement the java language *to its definition*.
Thats one reason it is final, if I *take* a String anywhere I can *rely* on it to *behave* as the java language defined a String behaves (because you can't create your own subclass that has different behavior).

Second, the immutability of String is "just" a design choice, but it has favorable implications in that again when you pass a String somewhere (e.g. as a File name), the API called can be sure you can't change the string and directly store references to it (as opposed to as make a copy of it if it were mutable). It also significantly simplifies working with String in multithreaded environments.

So why is StringBuilder/Buffer final? This is again "just" a design choice, but there aren't any as strong and obvious justifications behind it as there are for String. They just did it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having a misconception about "final" keyword when used with class.
When a variable is declared final it's value can't change once they are initialized.

i.e.

```
final int i=5;
      i++// Will give an error.
```

**But:**

**In case of classes:**
Final keyword servers the purpose of making the class non-inheritable i.e. that class can't be sub-classed!.
i.e.

```
final class question
{}
class answer extends question//Will give an error!!!
{}
```

**Answer to your question:**

Now, you are right that string is immutable because once a string object is initialized it can't be changed and Stringbuilder and Stringbuffer are mutable(Vice - Versa), and this has got nothing to do with these classes being final!
You aren't subclassing them right!

I hope I helped!

**Edit:**

I think I should explain this completely that how Stringbuilder is mutable and String is not:

I'll explain this code by code:

```
Stringbuilder a = new Stringbuilder("a");//Initial String!!
a.append("b"); //Now the String is ab!!
```

So, since the same object i.e. **a** got its value changed it is known as mutable.(An object i.e. capable of changing its value after being initialized).

**Now String:**

```
String a = "a";
a = a + "b"; //Explained below.
```

Though to you this may appear that string object **a** is changing its value and hence is mutable but it's not, as behind the scenes Stringbuilder is working.
i.e.
the actual thing did by compiler in the above code is:

```
a = new StringBuilder(a.append("b")); //The actual code...
```

So, now the variable **a** stores the values "ab".
I know this is confusing, but if you read my code precisely you will see that the object **a** never changed it's values it just got assigned a new value!!
This is what is known as being immutable i.e. an object cant change after being initialized!

I hope I helped

Comment: Right but then what makes it immutable?

Comment: @abhilash: Not exposing any mutation methods, forbidding subclassing, and guaranteeing that the results of methods are always the same.

Comment: And please do note that though I specified above that the variable a stores the value "ab", actually the variables in java don't store any value!. They just store the memory reference of the object actually stored in the memory(created using "new" keyword). I just said that to be simple in explanation!

Comment: And if you are asking how string class is immutable the answer is really simple! The data members inside java.lang.String class are final!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`String` is not immutable because it is final; `final` and immutability are more or less orthogonal.  Making a class `final` is *part* of *one* approach to making a class immutable, but making a class `final` is also part of a good programming practice in general no matter what behavior you want for the class.

An immutable class must not be extensible by outside users.  It may have several implementations inside its own package, like e.g. Guava's `ImmutableMap`, in which case the class need not be final, but you can also forbid extension by e.g. making constructors package-private so users outside the package cannot extend the class.

A `final` class is any class that cannot be extended.  This is recommended practice in *many* cases in Effective Java -- that is, whenever you don't have an explicit reason to make the class subclassable, making it final is generally good practice.

Answer (score 1):

**So what other factors are deciding for String to be immutable?**

The answer is simple as all the data member of String class is final which makes it as immutable.

If you want to make your own class immutable, make all the data members of that class as final. And initialise all the final data members in constructor so that once they have initialise, never changed.

If you will see **String** class implementation for immutability, you will find:

```
private final char[] value;
```

And initialisation of value will be in constructor part:

```
public String(String toCopy){

     value = toCopy.value;

}
```

And if you will see **StringBuffer** class implementation, you will find:

```
private char[] value;

public StringBuffer(String toCopy){

     value = toCopy.value;

}
```

So, in above code you can see, the **String** class's *value* data member will be once initialise and will never change but the **StringBuffer** class's *value* data member can be initialise and change many times.

**So this makes String class immutable not making a class final.**

Answer (score 0):

If you concern is around extending the behavior of StringBuilder or StringBuffer you can still do it - just not by inheritance. You can you composition or delegation. Classes String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder all implement CharacterSequence. So create you class implementing CharacterSequence and delegate all methods to the composed StringBuffer or StringBuilder. Composition over Inheritance is the golden rule in GoF - see this [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from) too.

Making a class final is an additional and more potent layer of encapsulation - maybe the author of the code does not feel anyone should be modifying the behavior by extension since s/he may feel a subclass of the class in question may not be truly representative of itself (in terms of conversion).

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` was the concept of mutable String, that is thread-safe, that is, all operations performed on it are synchronized.

`StringBuilder` is recommended replacement for `StringBuffer`. It was introduced, when it came out, that synchronization is not used very often, when it comes to Strings.

`String` is just String. Why is it immutable? Perhaps the reason was thread-safety and cost of such. What if you want to store global `String`, that is **read only**? If it was mutable, then all reads must have been synchronized - an additional overhead, that is not necessary here.

That's why these three classes were provided - **you** chose what do you want to pay for.

As you noted, all these classes - `String`, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` are final. The reason is that you can't (and shouldn't) modify behaviour of these classes.

It is better to implement another class, that contains (for example) `StringBuilder` and provide similar functionality, than extend it.

If you want, you may provide similar functionality by implementing [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) - all these classes implement this interface.